# How and the best way to retrieve a single entity google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two entity kinds (Person which has the properties first and last names; Second entity kind is Car which has the properties color and make). Using Java, how do I retrieve one specific entity (say the entity whos id/name is equal to 1) in the most efficient way? I have no built indexes and am using the default indexes Google app engine provides. Looking through google documentation, they provide examples of getting all records within a kind using a loop, but do not show how to get a specific entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each entity has a key (either autogenerated or provided by you) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Kinds_Keys_and_Identifiers and doing a `datastore.get` (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Retrieving_an_Entity) is the fastest way to fetch that entity. Any other query will generally be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed when I create an entity and I put in my own identifier (ex. "Bob"), the name\id is "Bob", but the key is some encrypted random string. So if I want to retrieve the entity which has the id/name "Bob", how would I know this random key for every entity if I wanted to retrieve it?

Comment: Oh I think I found the answer. So to confirm I understand this, you generate a Key object ex. Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "Bob");, then take that key and place it in a Entity person = datastore.get(k). Then from this object you can access the properties?

Comment: That's an encoded string. You can convert from the encoded key to a Key object with the methods of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory

Comment: yup, or you can recreate it from the string you used to create the key in the first place.